# Android SQLite update column using an Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

Considering the following SQLite Table

[image]

And the following snippet of code to update a *value* at a *"bit" position*, which is working fine.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("value", "1");

db.update("registro_status", values, "bit=1", null);
```

How can I set the whole "**value**" column at once using an Array like

`String[] valuearray = {"1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1"};`

?

Comment: If you want to update all rows together then, First of all you need to fetch all the bits in an array and then execute the update query in a for loop,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can't. However you can speed up your inserts by using one transaction context:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

db.beginTransaction(); 

try{
    int bit = 1;

    for (String value: valuearray) {
        values.put("value", value);
        db.update("registro_status", values, "bit=" +bit++, null);
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();

} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e(“Error in transaction”, e.toString());

} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

This is usually much faster than inserting record by record.

Alternatively, if you feel comfortable with SQL, you could implement an `INSERT` statement:

```
String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO registro_status (bit, value) VALUES ";
int    bit = 1;

for (String value: valuearray) {
    sql = sql+ "("+ bit +", " +value +"),";
}

// cut last comma and add semi colon
sql = sql.substring (0, sql.length() -1) +";";

db.execSQL(sql);
```

***p.s.***: please note updates above - I forgot the `update` ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, using your transaction context code doesn't return me any errors nor write anything on the database.

Comment: Guys please not that bit is like primary key for the row , and it is not like 1, , 3 .. non negative integer.
Read once my first comment @Machado

Comment: Please check my updates above; I forgot to invoke `update` - that could not work.

Comment: Indeed :D I made a Fiddle for the second one if you prefer it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/69ebf/1